# Dynamic SQL / Parameters / Search

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have searched on the forum and found some examples of how i can send a list of comma separated values to SQL and process them.

I wanted to know if i can create dynamic parameters and pass them to a stored procedure or some better way of making a particular task much easier?

I take a string and create an array of 'space' separated values and then for each of those values create a new parameter (eg SearchText0, SearchText1, etc).

```
For Each item In Searchstring
Parameters.(New SqlParameter("@SearchText" + Array.IndexOf(Searchstring, item).ToString, item)))
Next
```

The problem occurs when running the stored procedure as if there are too many parameters created from the array the SP will not execute, to little works fine as i can treat a parameter as an empty value.

```
@sUsercode as varchar (10) = '',
@SearchText1 as varchar (300) = '',
@SearchText2 as varchar (300) = '',
@SearchText3 as varchar (300) = '',
@SearchText4 as varchar (300) = ''

AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP (20) ProdTBL.Material + ' | ' + ProdTBL.Description + ' [' + ProdTBL.Plant + ']' AS Mat, ProdTBL.Material, ProdTBL.Description, ProdTBL.Plant 
FROM SCodes INNER JOIN ProdTBL ON SCodes.Plant = ProdTBL.Plant WHERE (SCodes.UserCode = @sUsercode) AND (ProdTBL.Bin <> 'DSCNTD') AND 
(ProdTBL.Material LIKE '%' + @SearchText1 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Description LIKE '%' + @SearchText1 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Plant LIKE '%' + @SearchText1 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Manuf LIKE '%' + @SearchText1 + '%') AND
(ProdTBL.Material LIKE '%' + @SearchText2 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Description LIKE '%' + @SearchText2 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Plant LIKE '%' + @SearchText2 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Manuf LIKE '%' + @SearchText2 + '%') AND
(ProdTBL.Material LIKE '%' + @SearchText3 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Description LIKE '%' + @SearchText3 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Plant LIKE '%' + @SearchText3 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Manuf LIKE '%' + @SearchText3 + '%') AND
(ProdTBL.Material LIKE '%' + @SearchText4 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Description LIKE '%' + @SearchText4 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Plant LIKE '%' + @SearchText4 + '%' OR ProdTBL.Manuf LIKE '%' + @SearchText4 + '%')
END
```

I know i can write the command string and run it like that but i would like to be able to not worry about anyone having to touch vbcode and just make changes to the stored procedure.

There are around 50 columns and i want to allow users to search around 10 of them without making the SP huge and without having to add a new row for every potential parameter that is created in the vbcode.

Thanks in advance.
Kev

Comment: you can combine all the values and pass them to one parameter, and split them out in your stored procedure and generate/run dynamic query statement using those values.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and split the string into a temp table in the stored procedure and tried a cross join against the table i wanted the values from. The performance in comparison to the above was poor, and the more values in the passed string the slower it got. The above method although terrible, performs better. One of the main issues with the above is that i have to limit the amount of search terms so that i know how many parameters to pass to the stored procedure which i have set to 10. This method would become real messy if i had to do a like against each parameter in 20 columns :(

Comment: T-Sql is not good at parsing but should not be that bad. Show us your code if you want to. For better parsing, you should build your dynamical query statement outside sql server, in your program code. I'm also guessing sql server is not doing very good job optimizing dynamic queries.

Comment: This use-case smells of "square-peg-into-round-hole"-ness, but I can sympathize.  For a pure-SQL solution, I would define the SP as having one VARCHAR(max) search parameter, and break it up (parse it) into a temp-table or table-var, then loop over it and build a dynamic-SQL query with the variable # of "WHERE" conditions.  But if it makes sense, I'd build an ad-hoc query in code and just call it using ODBC, because it'd be easier to manage that way.